# how to add a loader image on fadeout

Tags: jquery

how to add a loader image on fadeout in jquery. I am able to fadeout but I could not add a loading image on fadeout

```
$(".form1,.form2").fadeOut(800).load('src','loader.jpg').fadeIn()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't able to load image using load function... 
Load function in jquery will load a page (Similar to iframe);
You can  create image tag with loader image in src and use style to hide then use like

```
<script>
$('.form1').fadeOut(800, function() {         
         $("#loader").show();      
  });

$('.form1').fadeIn(800, function() {
    $("#loader").hide();      
});
</script>
```

Also Please visit the link, http://jsfiddle.net/emVyb/